# How does comma separated operations work in perl?

Tags: perl

I am currently studying Perl programming and am running into statements like this:

```
return bless { }, $type;
```

I know what `return bless { };` would do, and I also know what `return $type;` would do, but how does separating them by a comma affect the statement, and does it work the same way for all unary operators?

Comment: bless has two variants: `bless REF,CLASSNAME` and `bless REF`.  The notation shown is equivalent to `return bless(REF,CLASSNAME);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) is not an unary operator, so what happens is that `$type` gets passed to `bless` (where it is used as the name of the class to bless the hashref into).

The only thing special about [return](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) is that the expression on its right-hand might be evaluated in list, scalar, or void context depending on the context the subroutine was called in.

The [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) is not interpreted any differently in a `return` statement than it would be anywhere else (except that you can't tell whether it's in list or scalar context by looking at the `return` statement).

Comment: So all the comma ever does in perl is separate elements in a list?

Comment: @chustar, "In scalar context it evaluates its left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right argument and returns that value."  In list context, it just separates items in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Predefined Perl functions can be called with or without parentheses. Most of people coming from other languages confuse these functions for keywords/operators.

bless, undef, push, pop, shift, unshift, print, split, join, etc. are all functions.

Hence, these two are equivalent:

```
 return bless { }, $type;
 return bless({ }, $type);
```

But these two are not:

```
 print 2 * 3 + 2; # prints 8
 print(2 * 3) + 2; # prints 6 (with a warning if warnings pragma is on)
```

Comment: *Declared* Perl functions can be called with or without parentheses.  Builtins aren't special in this regard.

Comment: You're right, sub a {}; a 1,2; works but a 1, 2; sub a{} doesn't.